# How to change network buffer of network interface to get errors?

Tags: ethernet

I tried with `sudo ethtool -G eth0 rx 1020`, but im getting this error `Cannot get device ring settings: Operation not supported`. Is there any other way to change network buffer to simulate NIC card errors and Packet drops. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Netem can simulate all kinds of packet delay, corruption etc.http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem

Comment: yes we can use "netem", it simulates packet delay and packet loss. But that is at network layer level. I need at NIC card level, If I use "netstat -i" it must show the RX Erros and PKT_DROPS.